# Html difference in box models

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've been tinkering with a couple of websites and I noticed that their `html` tags had different default box model sizes even though both of them were set to 100% in the stylesheet. I tried changing a few values, but I can't seem to pin down the root of where the difference stems from.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaIFj.png]

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Two html tags, two different websites, both html tags are set to 100%, yet one website has a default box model of 1074x283 and the other 1288x339

Comment: Differently sized windows.

Comment: Hmm? Both websites are open in the same browser, in adjacent tabs and neither is open in Responsive Design mode.

Comment: Alright, I think I narrowed it down, the latter one would force one of the inner containers to have a width of 1170px when the screen had a min-width of 1200px, which I guess screwed with the dimensions of the html tag.